# How do I set and use shell variables?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

```
IRSTLM=$HOME/irstlm
```

I need help setting this variable up. Was wondering if this is correct syntax

```
IRSTLM=/home/user/irstlm
```

Is that possible to run from root? I need it to be done in root in order to access certain files, I can also add the rest of the command I am trying to run if you'd like to see the context it's being used inn.

New problem, don't know why but shouldn't this output the file with extension .arpa ? i dont seem to get that file and I require it to run the next command to finish compiling this program.

```
~/irstlm/bin/add-start-end.sh  < ~/corpus/news-commentary-v7.fr-en.true.en > news-commentary-v7.fr-en.sb.en export IRSTLM=$HOME/irstlm; ~/irstlm/bin/build-lm.sh -i  news-commentary-v7.fr-en.sb.en  -t ./tmp  -p -s improved-kneser-ney -o news-commentary-v7.fr-en.lm.en
```

Here is the full command:

```
/home/user/irstlm/bin/add-start-end.sh  < /home/user/corpus/news-commentary-v7.fr-en.true.en > news-commentary-v7.fr-en.sb.en export IRSTLM=$HOME/irstlm; /home/user/irstlm/bin/build-lm.sh -i  news-commentary-v7.fr-en.sb.en  -t ./tmp  -p  -s improved-kneser-ney -o news-commentary-v7.fr-en.lm.en
```

Comment: Please do provide more context! rootie tootie toot :)

Comment: I updated the post with the full command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks for the suggestions, they definitely helped, here the final command I ran, it seems I wasn't correctly setting the variable as "irstlm=/root/irstlm" final command:

```
 /root/irstlm/bin/add-start-end.sh < /home/user/corpus/news-commentary-v7.fr-en.true.en> news-commentary-v7.fr-en.sb.enexport IRSTLM=$HOME/irstlm; /root/irstlm/bin/build-lm.sh -i news-commentary-v7.fr-en.sb.en -t ./tmp -p -s improved-kneser-ney -o news-commentary-v7.fr-en.lm.en
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's a one-off command, you're better of just setting it for that command, i.e.:

```
IRSTLM=/home/user/irstlm /home/user/irstlm/bin/add-start-end.sh  \
  < /home/user/corpus/news-commentary-v7.fr-en.true.en > news-commentary-v7.fr-en.sb
```

If it is part of a script use:

```
export IRSTLM=/home/user/irstlm
/home/user/irstlm/bin/add-start-end.sh < /home/user/corpus/news-commentary-v7.fr-en.true.en > news-commentary-v7.fr-en.sb
```

Comment: And if it needs to be persistent across shell sessions, use the .bashrc or whatever other dotfiles are relevant.